# Select all nulls but only one not null

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I hope you will help me on this one:
I have a tale with this data

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T
(
    SG char(3) NOT NULL,
    SEQNUM int NOT NULL,
    CO varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    FS varchar(12),
    RS varchar(12)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.T(SG,SEQNUM,CO,FS,RS)
VALUES
('054',0,'010','P1',NULL),
('054',1,'010','P2',NULL),
('054',10,'020','P3',NULL),
('054',11,'030','P4',NULL),
('054',12,'030','A1','A1'),
('054',13,'030','P5',NULL),
('054',14,'030','P6',NULL),
('154',10,'150','P7',NULL),
('154',14,'160','A2','A2'),
('154',15,'160','P8',NULL)
```

What I need to achieve is this output

```
SG  SEQNUM  CO  FS      RS
054 0       010 'P1'    NULL
054 1       010 'P2'    NULL
054 10      020 'P3'    NULL
054 12      030 'A1'    'A1'
154 10      150 'P7'    NULL
154 14      160 'A2'    'A2'
```

So basicaly the logic behind this is whenever FS = RS keep only this entry and sort out all other with the same SG and CO. In the other cases keep the data.
Sorry for my bad english.
I hope you get what I mean :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It's great you've posted sample data as DDL+DML, however the logic isn't entirely clear. Why are the next rows not in the desired output? `'054',13,'030','P5',NULL`, `'054',14,'030','P6',NULL`, `'154',15,'160','P8',NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a NOT EXISTS for this

```
select *
from dbo.T t
where not exists
( 
  select 1
  from dbo.T d
  where d.SG = t.SG and d.CO = t.CO
    and d.FS = d.RS
    and (t.FS IS NULL OR t.RS IS NULL OR t.FS <> t.RS)
);
```

Which can also be done via a left self-join that filters the unmatched.

```
select t.*
from dbo.T t
left join dbo.T d
  on d.SG = t.SG and d.CO = t.CO
 and d.FS = d.RS
 and (t.FS IS NULL OR t.RS IS NULL OR t.FS <> t.RS)
where d.SG is null
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be13e1ab479206784ddaba2f2b5c9dac)*

Please note that the test puts a combined index on SG & CO

Comment: Thanks Luk! Works like a charm :) but its really slow when it comes with lots of rows (~500 million). Is there a faster query for this?

Comment: @jigga I put an alternative. But don't know if it would be faster. (can only use limited sample data).  But you could also check if it needs an extra index.